# Pandas Find Best Match & Show Result in Table

Tags: python, pandas, find

I have a data table that looks like this below and I'm trying to find the closest match of each column for the years 1991-2019 to the current year (2020). In the end, i need a table like the following showing the result of the find process.

Data table (daty):

```
      soi     ao   nao   pna       epo       wpo
Date                                            
1990 -0.7 -0.210  1.18 -0.46 -0.285904  0.763053
1991 -1.5 -0.112  0.61  1.15 -0.418762  0.850752
1992  0.1 -0.640 -0.28 -1.13  0.679149 -0.788247
1993 -0.7 -0.361 -0.41 -0.97 -1.228830 -0.447579
1994 -1.6 -0.084 -1.14 -2.02  0.193085 -0.912737
1995  0.3 -0.549  0.45  1.22 -0.658217  0.621721
1996  0.6 -1.140 -0.69 -0.27  0.394934 -1.161684
1997 -1.4  0.195  0.74  0.22  0.138353  0.414802
1998  1.0 -1.050 -1.80  0.42  0.254834  0.563291
1999 -0.1  0.059  0.50  0.33  0.176403  0.587210
2000  0.9  0.395 -0.06 -1.21 -0.303799 -0.809344
2001  0.2 -0.707 -0.49  0.04  0.429597  1.082077
2002 -0.6 -0.043 -0.54  0.60 -0.117497 -0.012490
2003 -0.1  0.467  0.16  0.59  0.172270 -0.503114
2004 -0.3  0.855  0.52 -0.11  0.611507 -0.055418
2005  0.4  0.802  0.76  1.32  0.117412  0.628558
2006 -0.6  0.606 -1.43  0.31 -0.439056 -0.666251
2007  0.2  0.179  0.85  1.52 -0.091188  0.887357
2008  1.2 -0.327  1.14  0.89 -0.146648 -0.444564
2009  0.3  0.875  1.62  1.03  0.747285  0.223464
2010  2.2 -0.865 -0.62  1.07 -0.322557  0.002758
2011  1.0  0.665  0.67 -0.39  1.035278  1.146269
2012  0.2  0.772 -0.43 -0.39 -0.006886  0.560083
2013  0.3 -0.461  0.38  0.41  0.451967  0.600924
2014 -0.7  0.102  1.72  0.78 -0.343152 -0.453856
2015 -1.6 -0.165 -0.49 -0.80  0.394162 -1.161164
2016  1.2  0.781  0.74  0.11  0.104103  0.189280
2017  0.6 -0.492 -0.45 -0.32  0.084595 -0.268721
2018 -0.9  0.585  1.78  1.16 -1.217344 -1.947052
2019 -1.2  0.306 -0.01  1.62 -0.006176  0.676129
2020  0.9  0.631  1.11  0.59 -0.398920 -0.165507
```

The final result for example needs to look like this:

```
  index     0  
0   soi  2010  
1    ao  2009  
2   nao  2018  
3   pna  2019  
4   epo  2011  
5   wpo  2011
```

I've tried using argsort in this form but i cannot figure out how to extract the best match maybe in a loop for each column and create the result in the table form. `daty.iloc[(daty['soi']-input).abs().argsort()[:1]]`. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your question does not match the output. It sounds like you are trying to find the year with the values that are closest to the values of 2020 for each index. You are simply showingg the max. What is your desired output? Can you either change the wording of your question or change your desired output? IT seems like one of them is wrong.

Comment: I'm showing the year in which the max value appears. Wasn't that the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df.iloc[:-1].sub(df.iloc[-1]).abs().idxmin()
```

Output:

```
soi    2000
ao     2006
nao    2008
pna    2003
epo    1991
wpo    2017
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That returns the index position for me `Date    29
soi     10
ao      16
nao     18
pna     13
epo      1
wpo     27`

Comment: Did you set `Date` as the index as shown in your sample data?

Comment: not my question, but you just alleviated my confusion. Thank you! I had a longer solution but this is so much better.

Comment: perfect solution although i'm not sure i understand it - what is .sub? And, how does idxmin work here? Yes, i used "Date" as the index in the large table data. thank you!

Comment: @user2100039 sub stands for subtract. Just easier to chain with it. Basically, the solution is: subtract the last rows from every other rows (.sub), take the absolute values of the differences (.abs), then find the index of the minimums in each column (.idxmin).

Comment: this is really a nice solution - thank you and i hope to code as well as you someday!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that as follows:

```
df.idxmax(axis='index')
```

For your data set this evaluates to:

```
soi    2010
ao     2009
nao    2018
pna    2019
epo    2011
wpo    2011
dtype: int64
```

To test this, I created the dataframe from your post like:

```
from io import StringIO
infile= StringIO(
"""Date  soi     ao   nao   pna       epo       wpo
1990 -0.7 -0.210  1.18 -0.46 -0.285904  0.763053
1991 -1.5 -0.112  0.61  1.15 -0.418762  0.850752
1992  0.1 -0.640 -0.28 -1.13  0.679149 -0.788247
1993 -0.7 -0.361 -0.41 -0.97 -1.228830 -0.447579
1994 -1.6 -0.084 -1.14 -2.02  0.193085 -0.912737
1995  0.3 -0.549  0.45  1.22 -0.658217  0.621721
1996  0.6 -1.140 -0.69 -0.27  0.394934 -1.161684
1997 -1.4  0.195  0.74  0.22  0.138353  0.414802
1998  1.0 -1.050 -1.80  0.42  0.254834  0.563291
1999 -0.1  0.059  0.50  0.33  0.176403  0.587210
2000  0.9  0.395 -0.06 -1.21 -0.303799 -0.809344
2001  0.2 -0.707 -0.49  0.04  0.429597  1.082077
2002 -0.6 -0.043 -0.54  0.60 -0.117497 -0.012490
2003 -0.1  0.467  0.16  0.59  0.172270 -0.503114
2004 -0.3  0.855  0.52 -0.11  0.611507 -0.055418
2005  0.4  0.802  0.76  1.32  0.117412  0.628558
2006 -0.6  0.606 -1.43  0.31 -0.439056 -0.666251
2007  0.2  0.179  0.85  1.52 -0.091188  0.887357
2008  1.2 -0.327  1.14  0.89 -0.146648 -0.444564
2009  0.3  0.875  1.62  1.03  0.747285  0.223464
2010  2.2 -0.865 -0.62  1.07 -0.322557  0.002758
2011  1.0  0.665  0.67 -0.39  1.035278  1.146269
2012  0.2  0.772 -0.43 -0.39 -0.006886  0.560083
2013  0.3 -0.461  0.38  0.41  0.451967  0.600924
2014 -0.7  0.102  1.72  0.78 -0.343152 -0.453856
2015 -1.6 -0.165 -0.49 -0.80  0.394162 -1.161164
2016  1.2  0.781  0.74  0.11  0.104103  0.189280
2017  0.6 -0.492 -0.45 -0.32  0.084595 -0.268721
2018 -0.9  0.585  1.78  1.16 -1.217344 -1.947052
2019 -1.2  0.306 -0.01  1.62 -0.006176  0.676129
2020  0.9  0.631  1.11  0.59 -0.398920 -0.165507"""
)

df= pd.read_fwf(infile).set_index('Date')
```